# Why does the compiler allow vector.begin()=vector.end() in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, std

While learning about **iterators** in **C++** I tried the following:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.end()=a.begin();
    //Why is this even allowed by the compiler?
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why should that specifically be forbidden? And what do you think that line does?

Comment: Well, as far as I know if I do the same with a member function of a class the compiler complains because it must be a modifiable lvalue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard doesn't specify whether `std::vector::iterator` is a class type, or a raw pointer.

If it is a class type then this code calls `operator=` on the temporary object returned by `a.end()`. Not a very useful operation, but legal. (Rvalues may have functions called on them).

If your library makes `std::vector::iterator` be a pointer then this code would fail to compile, since simple assignment requires an lvalue on the left.

Jarod42 pointed out that if the iterator's assignment operator had been defined as:

```
std::vector::iterator& std::vector::iterator::operator =(std::vector::iterator) &;
```

then this code would be illegal; the trailing `&` means that the function is only selectable when it is being called on an lvalue.

But it wasn't defined that way, I would guess that the Committee didn't want to make some legal code illegal for no good reason; maybe  there is a use case for it that nobody thought of yet.

Comment: re "I would guess that the Committee didn't want to make some legal code illegal for no good reason", much in C++ does not have any specific reason. but it's a practical language, so things that clearly did not work have been shaved off. since the rules here permit code that may compile with one compiler and not with another, a reasonable conclusion is just that that's never been a significant problem: it's not been shaved off.

Answer (score 10):

it would not be posiible if for example function end would return a pointer.

For example this code will not be compiled

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

std::end( a ) = std::begin( a );
```

GCC issues error

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
  std::end( a ) = std::begin( a );
                ^
```

However when objects of class types are used then they can call the ovetloaded copy (or move) assignment operator.

So the question arises why do not the functions return constant iterator objects. I think that it would be possible to apply `operator ++`. For example

```
auto it = ++c.begin();
```

For direct access iterators as pointers you can write simply

```
auto it = begin( a ) + 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

The line affect a temporary iterator, and so is useless.

`std::vector::iterator = std::vector::iterator` is allowed.

A way to disallow that would be to have

```
std::vector::iterator::operator =(std::vector::iterator) &; // note the extra &
```

but `std::vector::iterator` may be a simple pointer, and we can't disalow `T* = T*`

Comment: Can you explain exactly what does the `&` at the end of the function declaration do?

Comment: @Svalorzan it means that the function is only a viable candidate when called on an lvalue

Comment: Plus, ref qualifiers were introduced into the language waaaay later than STL was.

Comment: re "we can't disalow T* = T*", that's already invalid for temporaries, which is likely the source of the OP's confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign to an rvalue (aka temporary) primitive type in C++, like `(int)7` or a pointer returned by-value from a function.  This makes lots of sense, as the result of the assignment would be immediately discarded, so it is probably not what the programmer wanted.  rvalue means 'right hand side of the `=` sign' from language grammars, or a temporary (anonymous) value.

However on objects of class type, `=` just invokes `operator=`.  Usually when the lhs is an rvalue, this would make no sense, but sometimes it would (say, the class is a proxy object pseudo-reference (like what `[]` on `std::vector<bool>` returns).  So it is treated nit at all special, it just invokes the method.  And there was no way to tell if the method was invoked from a temporary rvalue or a 'real' lvalue.

rvalue references are new in C++11, as are rvalue qualified methods.

Prior to C++11, there was no way to block calling `operator=` on an object of class type just because it was a temporary.

As `begin` returns a non-const temporary, if it is of class type (not guaranteed by the standard) it can be assigned to.

Today we can block assignment to temporaries of class type, but the standard library has not been modified to block it on its types.  Probably at least partly to avoid backwards compwtibility issues, and partly to determine best practices outside `std` first.

Comment: Actually a.begin() = a.end() is possible on prior C++11 as well.

Comment: @nipun I said it was not possible to **block** it only for rvalues prior to C++11.  Or did I miss a negation?

Comment: I think I haven't understand correctly what you are pointing to. But we could always block operator= by making it private. Now, with c++11 we have deleted member functions which is an even easier way to block it.

Comment: @nipun You can block it, but not only for rvalues (prior to C++11).  `delete` is irrelevant.  In C++11 we can detect if the `this` object is being invoked in an rvalue context, and selectively block it.  This allows `=` in general, but blocks it when the lhs is an rvalue, just like primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

They are allowed because the iterator objects are copy-assignable and copy-constructible. That is why we can do something like a.begin() = a.end(). Also, we can do something auto it(a.begin()).

Check the examples below regarding copy-assignable.

```
#include <vector>

struct CopyConsAssignable
{
    int x;
    CopyConsAssignable(int a) 
    { 
        x = a; 
    }

    CopyConsAssignable(const CopyConsAssignable& other)
    {
        x = other.x;
    }

    CopyConsAssignable& operator=(const CopyConsAssignable& other)
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            x = other.x;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.begin() = a.end();

    CopyConsAssignable(2) = CopyConsAssignable(4); // Allowed as the objects are copy-assignable
    return 0;
}
```